# ошибка Traceback в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мой код:

```
def f(n):

    if n == 1:
        return 1
    if n == 2:
        return 2
    elif n > 2 and n % 2 != 0:
        return 7 * n + f(n - 3) / 9
    elif n > 1 and n % 2 == 0:
        return 5 * n + f(n - 1) + f(n - 2) / 9

print(f(50))
```

при выполнении программы выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 12, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 10, in f
  File "<input>", line 8, in f
  File "<input>", line 10, in f
  File "<input>", line 8, in f
  File "<input>", line 10, in f
  File "<input>", line 8, in f
  File "<input>", line 10, in f
  File "<input>", line 8, in f
  File "<input>", line 10, in f
  File "<input>", line 8, in f
  File "<input>", line 10, in f
  File "<input>", line 8, in f
  File "<input>", line 10, in f
  File "<input>", line 8, in f
  File "<input>", line 10, in f
  File "<input>", line 8, in f
  File "<input>", line 10, in f
  File "<input>", line 8, in f
  File "<input>", line 10, in f
  File "<input>", line 8, in f
  File "<input>", line 10, in f
  File "<input>", line 8, in f
  File "<input>", line 10, in f
  File "<input>", line 10, in f
  File "<input>", line 8, in f
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: а текст вашего `Traceback` мы должны угадывать ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: @n1tr0xs просто Traceback, все ж понятно ))

Comment: @Jack_oS согласен ;)

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: @gusen трейс в пайтоне читают снизу вверх... незачто!

Comment: @gusen добавил в ответ

Comment: Ошибка "TypeError", а traceback это отчет, в котором содержится информация об ошибке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что будет, если вызвать `f(0)`. Функция вернет `None` и тогда в рекурсии происходит вот что: `None/9`. Вам нужно определить поведение функции при входящем `n` меньше единицы, например так:

```
def f(n):
    if n < 1:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    if n == 2:
        return 2
    elif n > 2 and n % 2 != 0:
        return 7 * n + f(n - 3) / 9
    elif n > 1 and n % 2 == 0:
        return 5 * n + f(n - 1) + f(n - 2) / 9

print(f(50))
```

Так же непонятно для чего вам `elif`. Так же для чего вот эти сравнения (`n > 2`, `n > 1`, если код туда и так не должен дойти при невыполнении этих условий.

```
def f(n):
    if n < 1:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    if n == 2:
        return 2
    if n % 2 != 0:
        return 7 * n + f(n - 3) / 9
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return 5 * n + f(n - 1) + f(n - 2) / 9

print(f(50))
```

И рубрика, ставшая для меня любимой:

```
def f(n):
    return 0 if n<1 else 1 if n==1 else 2 if n==2 else 7*n+f(n-3)/9 if n%2 else 5*n+f(n-1)+f(n-2)/9
```

Или так:

```
def f(n):
    return 0 if n<1 else n if n in (1, 2) else 7*n+f(n-3)/9 if n%2 else 5*n+f(n-1)+f(n-2)/9
```

UPD:
Если вкратце, то функция, в которой не выполнился ни один `return`, делает его "сама" - `return None`. Для простоты представляете функции в своей голове так:

```
def f(x):
    # ваш код с ветвлениями, циклами и еще, бог весь чем
    return None # функция "сама добавляет" эту строку в конец себя.
```

Comment: Еще раз спасибо )

Comment: return n if n < 3 else 7*n+f(n-3)/9 if n%2 else 5*n+f(n-1)+f(n-2)/9